# How can I put DISPLAY name in frame-title of GNU EMACS

Tags: emacs

I use GNU EMACS on multiple monitors from a Windoze PC via VNC.

(Currently 5 - 4 big, 1 the small monitor on my tablet PC. Two vertical 1200x1920, two horizontal 1920x1200, plus the small.)

The way I am currently doing this is to run a separate VNC on each monitor. I then open a single emacs, and use make-frame-other-display to open emacs' frames in the other VNC window.

To make things more complicated - I run the VNCs on an up-to-date Ubuntu system, but I run the emacs on a quite out of date machine where the rest of the build tools live.  I.e. the VNC displays are not local to the same machine as emacs.

Rather than xhost+, I open an xterm in each of the VNCs, and ssh to the machine running emacs.  This creates DISPLAYS of the form localhost:16.0.  I then use make-frame-on-display using these localhost DISPLAYs.

This gets confusing.

It helps if I leave an "echo $DISPLAY" in the xterm windows.  Or chamnge the xterm's title.

I'd like to similarly change the EMACS' frames' titles, to reflect what each frame things is its current DISPLAY. But doing

```
(defvar frame-title-specific-ag "emacs"
 "title element from frame-title-format that is specific to a particular emacs instance; andy glew")
(setq frame-title-format
  (list
    "frame=%F "
    (format "%s" frame-title-specific-ag)
    " " 'system-name
    " DISPLAY="
    (getenv "DISPLAY")
    " %b"
    " " (format "pid:%d" (emacs-pid))
    " user:"(user-login-name))
  )
```

only gets the DISPLAY variable for the entire emacs.

Q: is there a way to find out the display associated with any particular frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the display name for the current frame, use

```
(frame-parameter nil 'display)
```

or replace `nil` with a specific frame to get the name of its display instead of the current one.  For example, use this to show the display in the title:

```
(setq frame-title-format
      '("DISPLAY=" (:eval (frame-parameter nil 'display))))
```

Note that it is important that this form is completely quoted, so the list that is used has an `:eval` which tells Emacs to run the code whenever it renders a frame title.  Without that, you might be tempted to write something like:

```
(setq frame-title-format
      (list "DISPLAY=" (frame-parameter nil 'display)))
```

but this doesn't work.  The problem is that the function call happens immediately when this form is evaluated, and the result is a list holding a particular string, which is the name of whatever frame was in effect this evaluation happened, and the string will not change magically.

Comment: Thanks. 99% of the way there.

Comment: @KrazyGlew You need to put your edit into the body of your question instead of editing the answer.

Comment: @KrazyGlew: I've updated the answer based on your suggested edit, and specifically explained why the second thing doesn't work.  As for your conclusion that the form that uses `:eval` doesn't work, I don't know what exactly is failing for you, but it works just fine for me: each frame has its display at the top.  This what I would expect, since the format variable is used to render the title when the current frame is the one whose about to get the title.  Perhaps you're having some other issue, maybe a window manager that doesn't update the window titles...?

Comment: Seems silly to put the answer into the question. Q&A format is easy to understand.

Comment: @KrazyGlew: I don't know what seems silly to you, but the common expectation is to have one question and answers below it, rather than an answer that is effectively a dialog.  As for your recent suggested edit where you say that this doesn't work: please specify (in a comment, not in the answer) what is it exactly that doesn't work.  You keep claiming that it shows "the display of the current frame", where I clearly see two frames on two screens with different titles.

Comment: I added what I needed to make Barzilay's suggestion work in a separate answer below. I'm happy to click "accepted" on Eli's answer if he or I fix it to actually work.

Comment: @EliBarzilay: I have now added those corrections in a separate answer. BTW, it is possible that I have an old emacs, 21.4.1 (I am plagued by old software at work where I lack root) - but I can assure you that with your answer I had two frames on two displays with the same display name in the title, changing as I selected different frames.

Comment: EliBarzilay: I agree, there is a distinction between answers and questions. What was silly was @MarkHall was asking me to put my corrections to your answer in the question.

Comment: @KrazyGlew: version 21.* is *ancient*!  You should just get the source and build it yourself or you're bound to keep running into all kinds of problems.  It's definitely something that yo must specify in future questions.  (As for what Mark has asked you to do, he just said that it's better to update the question to give extra information or specify that information in comments, instead of starting an in-answer dialog.)

Comment: @EliBarzilay: I agree, I am plagued by old tools at work. Updating them all is, well, a pain, and not what I am paid for. I have blogged about this in http://blog.andy.glew.ca/2012/06/joel-tests-best-tools-money-can-buy-and.html - as in the Open Source version of "Do you have the best tools money can buy?" is "are somewhat recent versions of tools installed?"

Comment: I would have specified the extra info in a comment, but comments have limited formatting.  Hard to put a code example in place.

Comment: I accepted this answer, although it doesn't work on my old version of emacs. I will take Eli's word that it works on his.  (Yeah, yeah, I should have a more recent version in a virtual machine somewhere.)

Answer (score -1):

Eli Barzilay pointed us to

```
(frame-parameter nil 'display)
```

which is 90% of the way there.

The following puts the display associated with the currently selected frame in its frame title.

```
(setq frame-title-format
  '(
     "DISPLAY="
     (:eval (frame-parameter nil 'display))
    )
  )
```

Glew: This puts the display of the currently selected frame, at the time the frame is created
(e.g. via make-frame-on-display) in the
title. Since this may be a different frame, in a completely different
display, it is not always what is wanted.

The unquoted, un-:eval'ed, form, puts the display of the currently selected frame,
at the time the setq is evaluated, in the title. This is even less of what is wanted.

Here is what I ended up with:

I set the default frame-title-format as above.  But I do bnot really use it because I
hook the following:

```
(defun ag-set-frame-title (frame)
  "set frame-title to glew preference, optional arg FRAME / default nil (currently selected frame)"
  (interactive)
  ;; TBD: make-variable-frame-local is deprecated in more recent versions of emacs
  ;; than the antiquated version at my work. use modify-frame-parameters instead
  (let (x)
    (setq x
      (concat
    (or frame-title-specific-ag "emacs")
    " " system-name
    " DISPLAY=" (frame-parameter frame 'display)
    " " (format "pid:%d" (emacs-pid))
    " user:" (user-login-name)
    ;;" " (buffer-name)
    )
      )
    (modify-frame-parameters frame (list (cons 'title x)))
    )
  )

;; TBD: this old emacs does not have modern hooks
(setq after-make-frame-functions '(ag-set-frame-title))
```

For good measure:

```
(defun ag-fix-frame-titles ()
  "run ag-set-frame-title on frame-lits"
  (interactive)
  (mapc 'ag-set-frame-title (frame-list))
  )
(ag-fix-frame-titles)
```

NOTE: per comment string it is possible that the fix described here is only needed on an old version of emacs, such as 21.4.1. @EliBarzilay says not needed on whatever version of emacs he is using.

Subtract points all you want, folks. Truth.

Comment: *sigh*, I'm saying this for the third time now.  Your code is a very verbose way to do the exact thing that `frame-title-format` is doing, except that its slightly worse since it creates a fixed string.  In your last comment to my answer you said "fix it to actually work" but you **still** didn't say explicitly what's broken.  (And in case it wasn't clear, take my `setq` thing, put it in your `~/.emacs`, run a new Emacs, and specify what is broken in what you see.

Comment: I agree. Your fix for frame-title-format should have worked. It did not. At least on the version of emacs I was using. I provided exactly that syntax in my original edit to your answer, which was rejected and/or overwritten. I probably have in in Mercurial. // Look man, I thank you for your answer. It pointed me in the right direction. Like I said, 99% of the way there in the first draft is not bad.

Comment: BTW, I suspect that the difference is that in the older emacs I am using the frame-title-format is evaluated BEFORE the newly created frame is selected.  Whereas this has been fixed in later emacs.